# How can i get the text from this element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

The text I need is: "BLABLA" from this code:

```
<td id="1" title="something">
    <span>text</span>
    <img src="pic.png"></img>
    <span><font>something</font></span>
    BLABLA
</td>
```

I can select the `<td>` element with `id`, but if I try to get the `innerHTML` value, I get the whole code inside the `<td>` element.

Comment: Use jquery , `$('#1').text()` simple as that

Comment: @siddhantsankhe that would also return text and something, OP only wants BLABLA

Comment: @johndoel couple of things with your html - img tags don't need a closing tag, font tags are obsolete - don't use them

Comment: this is not my code:D, i dont have jQuery

Comment: Read the other answers too - there is some native js answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [lastChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp) property to get the last element of a container.

```js
let MyElement = document.getElementById("1").lastChild.data.trim();
console.log(MyElement);
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1" title="something">
            <span>text</span>
            <img src="pic.png"></img>
            <span><font>something</font></span>
            BLABLA
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```